# Integrating Java CAS Server and Python CAS Client

Tags: java, python, django, cas

I have 3 web applications and a CAS Server. Two of applications and CAS server are in Java and work correctly, but I want my third application witch is in Python to use CAS server for authentication. **How can I implement this?**

I tried to use [this client](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Pycas) but it didn't work, and also there is no example to use this client with Django on the web.

Is there any other CAS client or an example of using [this client](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Pycas)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

There is a client for Django, see: https://www.casinthecloud.com/techservice.html#casclient.